# ASP.NET MVC - Best way to retain search criteria across all pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, cookies

I am writing a real-estate related ASP.NET MVC application. I would like to auto populate the  the user's (detected) location (city, state) when the site loads and allow them to search for using a different location. Location search is available on *all* pages on the site and I would like to preserve the most recent location value across all requests. Right now I'm planning to use cookies to preserve this data across all requests so it can be populated in all my views (via a layout file) but wonder if there is a better way of doing so.

I'd like to hear any suggestions.

Thank you,
JP

Comment: you could either use static variables or session variables.  To use session variables in MVC you use:

Answer (score 1):

you could either use static variables or session variables.  To use session variables in MVC you use:

```
  HttpContext.Current.Session["Location"] = "East St. Louis";
```

To recall in your view with Razor you use:

```
   @Session["Location"].ToString()
```